# How to take any CSV file and convert it to JSON?(with python as a script engine) [Novice user trying to learn NiFi]

Tags: json, apache, csv, apache-nifi

1) There is a CSV file containing the following information (the first row is the header):

```
first,second,third,total
1,4,9,14
7,5,2,14
3,8,7,18
```

2) I would like to find the sum of individual rows and generate a final file with a modified header. The final file should look like this:

```
[
{
"first": 1,
"second": 4,
"third": 9,
"total": 14
},
{
"first": 7,
"second": 5,
"third": 2,
"total": 14
 },
 {
"first": 3,
"second": 8,
"third": 7,
"total": 18
 }
 ]
```

But it does not work and I am not sure how to fix this. Can anyone provide me an understanding on how to approach this problem?
NiFi flow:
 [image: NiFi flow]

Comment: From the sample provided in the description, you haven't added anything. You just converted the csv input into JSON output. Are you implying that the CSV file wouldn't have the column `total`?

Answer (score 0):

Although i'm not into Python, by just googling around i think this might do it:

```
import csv
with open("YOURFILE.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    data = [r for r in reader]

import json
with open('result.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Query Record** processor and add new property as

**total**

```
select first,second,third,first+second+third total from FLOWFILE
```

Configure the **CsvReader controller service** with matching **avro schema** with **int** as **datatype** for all the fields and **Json Setwriter controller service**,Include **total** field name so that the **output from Query Record processor** will be all the columns and the sum of the columns as total.

Connect total relationship from Query Record processor for further processing

Refer to these links regarding [Query Record](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/121794/running-sql-on-flowfiles-using-queryrecord-process.html) and [Configure Record Reader/Writer](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/115311/convert-csv-to-json-avro-xml-using-convertrecord-p.html)